# Selected audio ports in pavucontrol not being used for audio

Tags: sound, microphone, pavucontrol

I am trying to use pavucontrol to control my audio ports on my Samsung Series 9 laptop.  I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

I am using pavucontrol because in 13.04, the standard Sound Options config page only offers me the "Analogue Stereo Output" profile, while pavucontrol offers all the options that previous versions of Ubuntu were offering.

I have a single combined headphone/mic audio jack.  If I plug something into this jack, pavucontrol automatically switches the output port to headphones - this makes sense, but if I manually switch the port back to speakers while the headphones are plugged in, the audio continues to play through the headphones.

No matter which input port I select ("Internal Microphone" or "Microphone"), it only takes the audio from the internal microphone.

Happy to provide any logs or output if this helps.